# Insert if equal mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like:

- level

  id: primary key

  order: interger
- plan

  id: primary key

  level: FOREIGN KEY (level)

  limit: interger
- request:
  id: primary key

  plan_id: FOREIGN KEY (plan)

When have a request, save data to request table, after that, I counting all request and compare with limit in table plan . If equal I insert data to table plan with level_id = level_id of order+1 in table level else do nothing. I implement it with multiple single query, but now I want optimize it in single query. Is this possible? Thank in advance

first:

```
INSERT INTO request(plan_id) SELECT id FROM PLAN WHERE ...
```

next:

```
  A =    SELECT COUNT(request.id) FROM request
     WHERE request.plan_id = ...


  B =  SELECT limit FROM plan
     WHERE  ...
```

IF A = B (I using php to compare)

```
INSERT INTO plan (level_id, order) SELECT id, order FROM level WHERE ..
```

else
noting to do

Comment: I don't quite understand the requirements. Why not include your existing queries so we can see the logic?

Comment: @Ben I'm in street right now so I can't include my queries, but I write a example queries of my logic. Can you help me

Comment: Please provide table with data and desire output for better understanding. I think you can achieve this using CTE.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the logic of what you're doing, but to answer your question, you can move what you currently have as queries for A and B into sub queries inside your insert. So something like:

```
INSERT INTO plan (level_id, order) 
SELECT id, order 
FROM level 
WHERE {existing where logic here}
AND (
       SELECT COUNT(request.id) FROM request
       WHERE request.plan_id = ...
    ) = (
       SELECT limit FROM plan
       WHERE  ...
    )
```

If the sub queries don't equal each other then the insert just won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think the UPDATE better be handled by writing a trigger watching the insertion on table request like this:

```js
CREATE TRIGGER level_trig AFTER INSERT ON request FOR EACH ROW

#new here represents the newly inserted row in request

@A := (SELECT COUNT(request.id) FROM request WHERE request.plan_id = new.plan_id)
@B :=  (SELECT limit FROM plan WHERE plan.id = new.plan_id)

if @A = @B then

#whatever your insert query was. I'm not very clear about that. 

INSERT INTO plan (level_id, order) SELECT id, order FROM level WHERE ..

end if;
```